# Cannot connect to Azure Cosmos DB (MongoDB flavour)

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I have set up a MongoDB in Azure Cosmos DB, and I am unable to connect to it. When creating the Cosmos DB, I have left all parameters default, except for the firewall: this I turned off. I can view the database through Azure's data explorer, but connecting to it from my local machine doesn't work. Below is the output of the Mongo client:

```
$ mongo my_acc.documents.azure.com:10255 -u <username> -p <password> --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --verbose
MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://my_acc.documents.azure.com:10255/test
2018-10-15T15:42:19.077+0200 D NETWORK  [js] creating new connection to:my_acc.documents.azure.com:10255
2018-10-15T15:42:24.111+0200 D -        [js] User Assertion: InternalError: couldn't connect to server my_acc.documents.azure.com:10255, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to my_acc.documents.azure.com:10255 (13.69.66.0:10255) :: caused by :: Connection timed out src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/mongo.cpp 756
2018-10-15T15:42:24.111+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server my_acc.documents.azure.com:10255, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to my_acc.documents.azure.com:10255 (13.69.66.0:10255) :: caused by :: Connection timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
2018-10-15T15:42:24.111+0200 D -        [js] User Assertion: Location12513: connect failed src/mongo/shell/shell_utils.cpp 343
2018-10-15T15:42:24.111+0200 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 4002929 limit: 0
2018-10-15T15:42:24.112+0200 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 283209 limit: 0
2018-10-15T15:42:24.112+0200 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 174369 limit: 0
2018-10-15T15:42:24.113+0200 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 1449 limit: 0
2018-10-15T15:42:24.113+0200 D -        [main] User Assertion: Location12513: connect failed src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/proxyscope.cpp 300
exception: connect failed
```

I have tried connecting from different machines from different networks using different tools, but none of them work. Am I overlooking something? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the connection string: did you grab that from the portal? (you probably did, but just asking, for completeness) - Under "Quick Start" - there's a MongoDB Shell tab, which contains the full connection string, including username (the name of your account) and password (a very long key). Also, are you on a network that blocks outbound ports? port 10255 is typically not open if behind a corporate firewall.

Comment: Yes, I grabbed the connection string from the quick start guide. Is there a quick way to test whether port 10255 is blocked? I have tried on two different networks, of which at least one shouldn't block any outbound ports, but is there any way to be sure?

Comment: Just tested again. The networks were indeed blocking the port. Thanks for the help!